# false is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am following "https://www.mandiant.com/blog/parsing-registry-hives-python/".

While running below code:

```
f = open("SAMPLE1.DAT")
buf = f.read()
regf = RegistryParse.REGFBlock(buf, 0, false) 

for HBIN in regf.hbins():
    for cell in HBIN.cells():
        if cell.is_free():
            print "Unallocated cell at offset 0x%x" % (cell.offset())
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'false' is not defined
```

What can the reason be?

Now, it came to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mig.py", line 11, in <module>
    regf = RegistryParse.REGFBlock(buf, 0, False) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Registry/RegistryParse.py", line 236, in         __init__
    raise ParseException("Invalid REGF ID")
Registry.RegistryParse.ParseException: Registry Parse Exception(Invalid REGF ID)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python is case sensitive. `False` != `false` != `fAlSe`

Answer (score 14):

[`False`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#False) should be capitalized in Python:

```
regf = RegistryParse.REGFBlock(buf, 0, False)
```

Remember that Python is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

Use `False` with an uppercase `F`:

```
regf = RegistryParse.REGFBlock(buf, 0, False)
```

Unfortunately, that blog post has that spelled wrong.